# Road Type Abbreviation Replacement in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a large spreadsheet in excel which has a column of 6000+ addresses. I want to convert any of the road type abbreviations to the typed out types.

examples: **Rd -> Road** or **St. -> Street.**

An issue I've encountered is that some addresses contain the sequence of letters I am trying to replace and the find and replace feature ends up replacing parts of the names of the streets in addition to replacing the abbreviations.

for example: **1123 Stupid State St** would be replaced by **1123 Streetupid Streetate Street**

Is there any way to write some code that would only change the abbreviations while preserving the rest of the address?

**Note:** All of the addresses do not follow the same format. The abbreviations fall in random places within the cell--that is to say that the abbreviations do not always appear at the end of the cell value.

This also needs to work for all road type abbreviations.

Thanks a ton for any help.

Comment: If this is something that you are doing only one-off as it seems you are, then I suggest you break up your column into individual words by using the "Text to Columns" command. Description of the feature here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/214261. Cheers,

Comment: can you show what the spreadsheet looks like? add image to que

Comment: Even if you look at each word individually then you may still run into problems. If you have St Marks Place in New York or any street in St Louis then how do you prevent your replacement algorithm from turning what should be "Saint" into "Street"

Comment: Just out of curiousity, why do you want to de-normalize your address column?  At least in the United States, [the USPS prefers](http://pe.usps.com/text/pub28/28c2_014.htm#ep526381) that "Street", "Road", "Avenue", etc. be abbreviated. See [Publication 28 - Postal Addressing Standards](http://pe.usps.com/text/pub28/welcome.htm).

Comment: It's not that I want to de-normalize the addresses; I want to be able to use vlookup and the addresses are a mixed bag of formats. I just want to turn all the formats to the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I think I resolved the issue. Text to Columns with a space delimiter onto a new worksheet, then checking the "match entire cell contents" in the find and replace. After all the abbreviations have been replaced, I will concatenate all of the columns back together and copy and paste the cells back to their original place.

Thanks for the help everyone. And thanks nbayly for the fix.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you tried Find and Replace, but I am guessing that you did not check the "Match Whole Word" advanced option. Do Find and Replace Again, click the Advanced button, and check the "Match Whole Word" checkbox. As long as your abbreviations are separated by a space from the street name, you should replace the abbreviation without touching the street name.

Comment: I don't believe that is an option in "Find and Replace". At least in Excel 2013. There is the "Match entire cell contents" but this wouldn't achieve the requested result. Can you check again if this option is available to you and what version of Excel you are using?

Comment: I think that's actually an option in Microsoft Word rather than in Excel

Comment: Oops, yes, you are both right. Are you comfortable using VBA? I can code something for you as a replacement answer.

Comment: I'd love that code seeing as the addin is incompatible with excel 2010 64 bit. I am comfortable with VBA, just less so with string manipulation.

Comment: Never mind about the code. See below for my solution.